# Load Different Launch Screen for iPad / iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone

i want to load different launch screen storyboard for iPad and iPhone & for that i add new entry in info.plist like below

[image]

but it load only iPhone launch screen.

any help will be appreciated.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you not using Assets catalog for launch images. This is the best solution from Apple.

Comment: @Gagan_iOS, thanks for reply. but i don't want to use launch images.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**Way 1:**
You have to use two xib's for this. One for iPad and the other one for iPhone. You have to name it as follows,

**iPhone**- LaunchScreen2~iphone.xib

**iPad** - LaunchScreen2~ipad.xib

or

**Way2:**
Open your Info.plist file. Create another entry as UILaunchStoryboardName~ipad and set it to your LaunchScreeniPad.xib.

Revert back in case if you face any difficulties

Comment: can i have to define different launch screen like in above image?

Comment: you can choose either way1 or way 2 . I tired both and it works for me

Comment: Be aware. The `~iphone.xib` suffix is case sensitive.

Comment: Excellent answer.

Answer (score 16):

You can use a single Storyboard to load different Launch images for iPad and iPhone. In your LaunchScreen.storyboard, go to the Attributes Inspector of the ImageView where you set the image. Set launch image for iPhone in Image field. There is a plus sign near the "Image" field. Click on it and change the Height from Compact to Regular and click Add Variation. Another field is created as wR hR. Add the launch image for iPad there. Thats it. Now it loads launch image based on your device.

[image]

Comment: 1st thing I don't want to use Images in `LaunchScreen`. 2nd thing is that I added multiple `UILabel` in `LaunchScreen` so the solution that you suggest is not working.

Comment: what screen size I need to use for ipad and iphone?