# Different background Image for Splash Screen for iPad for Landscape & Potrait Mode in LaunchScreen.storyboard

Tags: ios, ipad, orientation, size-classes

I need to set a different background image for iPad for both Landscape & Portrait mode in LaunchScreen.storyboard. I am unable to do that using size-classes as both of them have Regular-Regular size classes. Is there any way to do so? I have other UIKit elements in the LaunchScreen.storyboard as well. like another Imageview and Labels.

Comment: Short answer; you can't using a launch storyboard. You can only have one image, set it to aspectFill and accept the fact that there will be some image clipping depending on device rotation. The other alternative is to have a very simple launch storyboard (say a plain colour) and implement your splash screen in code as your first view controller.

Comment: Did you find the answer to your question?

Comment: @Vladislav This link might help you. Although I didn't tired it. Link:- https://github.com/jjochen/AdaptiveLaunchScreen

Answer (score 0):

Yes it works to differentiate iphone and ipad, but it can't differentiate between ipad landscape or portrait just because both L and P mode have wR and hR.

Answer (score -1):

you can follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53553735/7707)

> You can use a single Storyboard to load different Launch images for
>   iPad and iPhone. In your LaunchScreen.storyboard, go to the Attributes
>   Inspector of the ImageView where you set the image. Set launch image
>   for iPhone in Image field. There is a plus sign near the "Image"
>   field. Click on it and change the Height from Compact to Regular and
>   click Add Variation. Another field is created as wR hR. Add the launch
>   image for iPad there. Thats it. Now it loads launch image based on
>   your device.

Comment: Thanks for your post. But the problem is size classes for iPad for Landscape & Portrait mode is wR hR. I want to set a different image for this two orientation, which I am not able to. However, I am able to do that for the iPhone but not for iPad.